# How to handle sql exception in C#?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am using catch block with `SqlException`, but I want to show custom messages rather than exception itself.
So how do I filter out the messages. Like say I want to catch a `Unique Key` Constraint Violation. Is there some error code which i can use to determine the error.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                objuser.username = txt_email.Text;
                objuser.email = txt_username.Text;
                objuser.password = txt_password.Text;
                int i = BusinessUser.BusinessRegisterUser(objuser);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    Session["user_authenticate"] = "Verified";
                    Session["user_email"] = objuser.email; //  sql exception handle for uniqe key
                    Response.Redirect("user_registration.aspx");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            { 
              // Handle Exception here if e-mail already exists
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Number property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) of your SqlException. A full list of possible errors can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx).